# Can we get the Result of @InvocableMethod method in Process Builder or use that output for further decision?

Tags: apex, process-builder

I am calling the `@InvocableMethod` from the Process Builder and `@InvocableMethod` method is returning the result, how can I take the result and use in `Process Builder`?

```
public class GetAccountUsingPhone {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static List<Account> getAccountsUsingPhone(List<String> phones){
        System.debug('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~');
        System.debug('Phone Values :: '+phones);
        List<Account> accounts = [select Id, Name, AccountNumber, Phone from Account where Phone=:phones];
        System.debug('Accounts :: '+accounts);
        return accounts;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: From ~2 years ago: [accessing the return value of an InvocableMethod in process builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/83944/accessing-the-return-value-of-an-invocablemethod-in-process-builder/83946#83946). I'm not sure if anything has changed since then.

Comment: @Martine - Agree. There must be updates in Process Builder, we just need to found that out.

Comment: Unfortunately things have not changed AFAIK. Main reason is most likely due to being able to take whatever you would do with the return value and do it in the invokable method. since you already have to write code at that point anyway. Jut a guy on my part though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to get value returned by apex. 
Go through the link given below.[return values from process flow](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000su1ZQAQ)

but you can update some of your object fields that you can use in process builder.